# javascript, convert an array of objects to an array of arrays vertically

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a CSV file that I have successfully read in with `d3.csv`. The result is a JSON file where each line consists of an array element and each array element is an object with key/value pairs matching the column headers.

I need this in a "vertical" format, as an array of arrays, where each inner array consists of the value for each object.

Here is an example to run in Node:

```
> a = new Array();
[]
> a.push({"b":2, "c": 4, "d":6, "e": 8});
1
> a.push({"b":3, "c": 6, "d":9, "e": 12});
2
> a.push({"b":4, "c": 8, "d":12, "e": 16});
3
> a.push({"b":5, "c": 10, "d":15, "e": 20});
4
> a
[
  { b: 2, c: 4, d: 6, e: 8 },
  { b: 3, c: 6, d: 9, e: 12 },
  { b: 4, c: 8, d: 12, e: 16 },
  { b: 5, c: 10, d: 15, e: 20 }
]
> x = [[2,3,4,5],[4,6,8,10],[6,9,12,15],[8,12,16,20]]
[ [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ], [ 4, 6, 8, 10 ], [ 6, 9, 12, 15 ], [ 8, 12, 16, 20 ] ]
> x
[ 
  [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ], 
  [ 4, 6, 8, 10 ], 
  [ 6, 9, 12, 15 ], 
  [ 8, 12, 16, 20 ] 
]
>
```

Here, `[a]` represents the array of object I have while `[x]` represents the array of arrays I would like to have.

My data file is very wide and has many columns. I have tried several toy solutions, and I can iterate through the array, select each element, then iterate through each element and select each key, grab the value, and push it to a new array. However, this is nasty and very easy to break. Surely there is a better way.

If I had a list of lists, I could flip the rows and columns. Unfortunately, I have a list of object, read in with `D3.csv()`.

My primary language was (note, was) Perl, and a Perl-ish solution is natural to me. My current application runs client side in a browser, and I need a client side solution in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in a number of ways, but since it appears that all objects in your source array have the same properties, the most direct may be a nested [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) call. The outer `map()` is called on the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) of the first element of the array, and the inner `map()` uses each iterated key on every object in the source array.

```js
const a = [{ b: 2, c: 4, d: 6, e: 8 }, { b: 3, c: 6, d: 9, e: 12 }, { b: 4, c: 8, d: 12, e: 16 }, { b: 5, c: 10, d: 15, e: 20 }];

const result = Object.keys(a[0]).map(key => a.map(o => o[key]));

console.log(result);
```

---

If the objects had varying properties, you could use a [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) call to accumulate all the values of like properties.

```js
const a = [{ b: 2, c: 4, d: 6, e: 8 }, { b: 3, c: 6, d: 9, e: 12 }, { b: 4, c: 8, d: 12, e: 16 }, { b: 5, c: 10, d: 15, e: 20 }];

const result = Object.values(
  a.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key =>
      (acc[key] ??= []).push(obj[key]));

    return acc;
  }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @pilchard's `d3` agnostic answer; but if you're interested in a `d3` driven answer you can use [`d3.transpose`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/v2.12.0/README.md#transpose) on an array of arrays with a pre-processing step of removing the keys of the objects with `Object.values`:

```js
const a = [
  { b: 2, c: 4, d: 6, e: 8 },
  { b: 3, c: 6, d: 9, e: 12 },
  { b: 4, c: 8, d: 12, e: 16 },
  { b: 5, c: 10, d: 15, e: 20 }
]

const x = d3.transpose(a.map(o => Object.values(o)));

console.log(x);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```